# How can I minimize a code function that finds repeated values in an array of objects in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, object, if-statement

I need to fix this function, which must find two similar names in an array of objects.

I tried to do this, and it's working, but the *test* tells me that it should be just only one loop and one if

```
function searchByName() {
    const values = [
        { name: 'Johny Walker', birthDate: '1995-12-17' },
        { name: 'Andrew', birthDate: '2001-10-29' },
        { name: 'Viktor', birthDate: '1998-11-09' },
        { name: 'Andrew', birthDate: '2011-05-09' }
    ];

    for (let obj of values) {
        for (let elem of values) {
            if (obj == elem)
                continue;
            if (elem.name === obj.name && elem.age === obj.age) {
                console.log(obj);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

};
```

Here is the example that must come out:

```
[
  { name: 'Andrew', birthDate: '2001-10-29' },
  { name: 'Andrew', birthDate: '2011-05-09' }
]
```

Comment: Keep a map of anything you've encountered. You only need to process the array once that way.

Comment: *"It's work"*: well it doesn't, because it doesn't give that output.

Comment: could you show me some examples? I'm a beginner. I study and do the exercises, but I am stuck with this task

Comment: Your code just logs the duplicates, but your example output shows that they should be put into an array.

Comment: There's no `age` property in your objects. `.age` should be `.birthDate`

Comment: But if it's supposed to return both objects with `name: 'Andrew'` even though they have different birth dates, you shouldn't compare those properties at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just push names to the array and stop when there is a duplicate:

```
let hasDuplicates = [];
values.forEach((e, idx) => {
    if(!hasDuplicates.includes(e.name))
        if(idx !== values.length-1) { hasDuplicates.push(e.name); }
        else { hasDuplicates = false; }
    else { hasDuplicates = e; }
});
```

And then you can use that variable:

```
if(hasDuplicates) {...}
```

Answer (score 0):

- You can find the duplication count by `name` key using `Array.reduce` function.
- And from the duplication result, you can filter the duplicated ones only and show them using `Array.filter` & `Array.map`.

```js
const values = [
  { name: 'Johny Walker', birthDate: '1995-12-17' },
  { name: 'Andrew', birthDate: '2001-10-29' },
  { name: 'Viktor', birthDate: '1998-11-09' },
  { name: 'Andrew', birthDate: '2011-05-09' }
];

let duplicates = values.reduce((acc, cur) => {
  if (acc[cur.name]) {
    acc[cur.name].push(cur.birthDate);
  } else {
    acc[cur.name] = [ cur.birthDate ];
  }
  return acc;
}, {});

duplicates = Object.entries(duplicates).filter(([name, birth]) => birth.length > 1).map(([name, birth]) => {
  return birth.map((item) => ({
    name,
    birthDate: item
  }));
});
console.log(duplicates);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `reduce` method to iterate over the array and push items into the array. Then we just filter the array by its length. So if the length is greater than 1, it means we have found a duplicate:

```
const result = values.reduce((a, c)=> {
    a[c.name] = a[c.name] || {...c, items: []} ;
    a[c.name].items.push(c);
    return a;
}, { });

let result = Object.values(result).filter(f => f.items.length > 1).flatMap(s => s.items);
```

An example:

```js
const values = [

{ name: 'Johny Walker', birthDate: '1995-12-17' },
{ name: 'Andrew', birthDate: '2001-10-29' },
{ name: 'Viktor', birthDate: '1998-11-09' },
{ name: 'Andrew', birthDate: '2011-05-09' }

];

const result = values.reduce((a, c)=> {
    a[c.name] = a[c.name] || {...c, items: []} ;
    a[c.name].items.push(c);
    return a;
}, { });
console.log(Object.values(result).filter(f => f.items.length > 1).flatMap(s => s.items));
```